# Single-Sign-On with server-side application?

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, single-sign-on, server-side

I would like to process status updates of friends within a server-side application (like a server-side job).

I could create something like a configuration website to connect my application with facebook, let the user login, get the permissions, etc., but this should only be done once by the user. The (session-, access-, auth-, verification-, whatever-) keys or login information could be stored within a database and the server-side application/job could use these information from the database to access the status updates.

The problem is, that the user should only login once, so the user has not to login everyday manually to let the server-side application/job continually working.

Has someone an idea how this could get solved? It is very difficult to find working solutions/ideas for that problem, because Facebook is currently deprecating all these features (REST-API, Facebook-Connect, offline-access-permission, infinite session keys, ...). The Android apps have a similar requirement, but these seem to have the option to solve this problem via the mightly facebook app/integration which has some exceptions... At least all Android apps are working continually with my facebook data and I didn't saw a facebook login page for years. ;-)